# Correcly importing JSON files within a python package from an AWS's Lambda

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, serverless

A bit of context. I am working with a Serverless framework, and all of the code runs on an AWS's Lambda. I have a python package, which I am pulling from a private repo **A**. One of the classes I am using, loads the parameters from a JSON I have within the package **A** when initialised. When I run the code locally, I am able to successfully load the JSON and initiliase the class. But when I deploy everything, I am unable to locate the JSON and get the following error:

```
Provided json is not in a correct format: [Errno 2
] No such file or directory: '/var/task/sub_directory_that_i_need/the_file_i_need.json'
```

Code I use to retrieve within the package **A** to initialise the class I need:

```
        self.parameter_i_need = json.load(
            open(
                os.path.join(
                    os.path.realpath(
                        os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__))
                    ),
                    "sub_directory_that_i_need/the_file_i_need.json",
                ),
                "r",
            )
        )
```

I have also tried with sys path:

```
        self.parameter_i_need = json.load(
            open(
                os.path.join(sys.path[0], "sub_directory_that_i_need/the_file_i_need.json",),
                "r",
            )
        )
```

Which gives me the same error.

Any suggestions would be greately appreciated.

Comment: check if sub_directory_that_i_need is present in /var/task. you can use print(subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l", "/var/task"])) to check the contents inside /var/task.